# Why is using "++value" resulting in -842150449?

Tags: c++

Using this in `.h` file:

```
int value;
```

And this in `.cpp` file as loop:

```
std::cout << ++value << endl;
```

The result is this:

```
-842150449
-842150448
-842150447
-842150446
-842150445
-842150444
```

(.. and so on)

But why? The number makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Did you initialize `value` with any number? If not, then `-842150449` makes perfect sense, (just like any other number would make perfect sense).

Comment: What number did you expect after a number as been incremented which you cannot have any expectation about?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] to show us. Exactly *where* is this `value` variable defined (global scope, member variable, local inside a function, etc.)? How, if at all, is it initialized? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As you can see, all these numbers contain `42`, and so the program is working in perfect harmony with Magrathea's original design.

Comment: While I concur with what everyone is saying, `number` is not initialized, there isn't enough context to say for sure why. If your layout is as you *claim*, that there is some secret header that we can't see hosting just `int number;` within, and said-header is included in some secret `.cpp` that we can't see, *and* the line of code you're showing is somewhere within said-same, *and* `number` isn't being shadowed by some uninitialized local variable, then what your claiming happens.. *can't* . `number` is a global with static storage; it is zero initialized at startup. So post a *real* [mcve].

Comment: Jammonica, would you like to explain about the fact that you are including the header into more than one code file, one of which does a clean initialisation, while another one does the shown output? That would be very important information to helpfully answer your question. On a side note, it would also explain why you have an expectation about the value.

Comment: What number is "I have no earthly idea" plus one? You didn't tell the computer where to start from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int value;
> ```

This is syntax for default initialisation. Default initialised integer has an indeterminate value (unless it has static storage in which case it is zero initialised). The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined.

> But why? The number makes absolutely no sense.

Presumably because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Value has never been initialized, so you're trying to add 1 to something that "isn't there" so you get these garbage values from what is just being assigned there automatically. Try:

```
value = 1;
std::cout << ++value << std::endl;
```

in your .cpp file